# prove that a function is zero at every point of an interval under certain conditions that meet its nth derivative

Tags: calculus

let be $F: \mathbb{(-1,1)} \to \mathbb{R}$  a function  that has derivatives of all orders such that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$  for all $n \in \mathbb{N}-{0}$ and there is $c>0$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $Sup_{x \in \ (-1,1)}|f^{(n)}(x)|\le n!c^{n}$. show that $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in \ (-1,1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that, if $f$ satisfies the conditions given above and $f(0)=0$, then $f$ is zero on the whole interval. This is a consequence of the Denjoy-Carleman theorem (see big Rudin, Chapter 19). In general, the class of all infinitely diffentiable functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $\lvert f^{(n)}(x)\rvert \leq c_fC_f^n M_k$ , where $c_f,C_f>0$ are allowed to depend on $f$, is quasianalytic (i.e. has the property you described above) if and only if the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty M_k^{-1/k}$ diverges.

Comment: friend, thank you very much for your help but can only be used in demonstrating the basic theorems of differential calculus, made a mistake to contextualize the question